# Web Scraping with Selenium questions, no results with any method

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

When hitting inspect the element on a paragraph, I get directed to a  tag. If it is empty, Where is the text that I see on the screen coming from?

I have attempted:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('the class of the textarea')
driver.find_elements_by_id("the id of the textarea") 
driver.find_elements_by_class("the class of the textarea")
```

I've also tried the ladder methods with the parent divs of the text area. nothing.

Then I did the following:
I copied the text and cntrl+F to find it in the HTML, I was directed to a  tag. I tried the following:

```
everything = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("script")
for item in everything:
    print(driver.execute_script(item.text))
```

I get a list of Nones printed out.
I have been stuck at this for days.

This is the  tag:

```
<textarea style="width: 658px; height: 128px; overflow: auto;" autocomplete="off" id="ContentPH_description" name="ContentPH_description" role="textbox" aria-readonly="false" aria-required="false" aria-multiline="fals" class="x-form-textarea x-form-field vms-viewmode-view-set" readonly="" aria-labelledby="ContentPH_description_label" title="" aria-invalid="false" maxlength="10000" oldindex="0" tabindex="-1"></textarea>
```

I, unfortunately, **cannot share a link or the full HTML of the page since it is work-related and you'd need a login to access the data I am trying to scrape.**

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Can you share the url or html of the element you are trying to access?

Comment: @itronic1990 I have just updated the post. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: There is no text in the tag you shared. When this textarea is populated?

Comment: @itronic1990 That's where the confusion comes from. I can the text on the web page, and when I inspect it, I am direct to that textarea. but it stays empty in the code. I tried adding implicit waits to my program, and that didn't work. What do you reccomend?

Comment: What happens to this textarea during your manual testing?

Comment: Nothing but simply the class name shifting from "class="x-form-textarea x-form-field vms-viewmode-view-set" to class="x-form-textarea x-form-field vms-viewmode-view-set x-form-focus"

Comment: When is the text you are trying to access appears on the screen?

Comment: @itronic1990 As soon as I load the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help you, but when I try to access visual hidden text elements (i.e. text from a collapsed tab), I always replace `element.text` to `element.get_attribute('textContent')` or `element.get_attribute("innerText")`.

Comment: I just added that. It keeps spitting out None values until this error shows :"javascript error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: The PageRequestManager cannot be initialized more than once."

Comment: Another thing, why can't you `print(item.text)` in the first place? Do you really need `driver.execute_script()`?

Comment: I did, just to confirm I got the right script. But what I am after is the chunk of text data that the script tag generates. is there a way I can get that?

Comment: have you tried:

`everyting = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//textarea[@role="textbox"]')
for item in everything:
    print(item.text)`

Comment: Yes, that was one of my earliest approaches before even thinking about the script tag, still yields empty results.

Comment: Maybe try to wait for element ot be visible using  `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//textarea[@role="textbox"]')))` ?